# Mysql in Query to join query Optimisation

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

Trying to debug a slow query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(bt.transactionQuantity * bpd.unitPrice), 0)
FROM batchTransaction bt
LEFT JOIN batch b ON b.id = bt.batchId
LEFT JOIN batchPricingDetails bpd ON bpd.id = b.batchPricingDetailsId
WHERE (bt.productId, bt.dateCreated) IN (
    SELECT productId, MAX(dateCreated)
    FROM batchTransaction
    WHERE organisationId = '714361434540086498'
    AND dateCreated < 1689877800000
    GROUP BY productId
);
```

Instead of using in query trying to do join but it is giving erroneous results by a margin of greater than 10X.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(bt.transactionQuantity * bpd.unitPrice), 0)
FROM batchTransaction bt
JOIN (
    SELECT bt.productId, max(bt.dateCreated)
    FROM batchTransaction bt
    WHERE bt.organisationId = '714361434540086498' AND bt.dateCreated < 1689877800000
    GROUP BY bt.productId
) AS filtered_data ON bt.productId = filtered_data.productId
LEFT JOIN batch b ON b.id = bt.batchId
LEFT JOIN batchPricingDetails bpd ON bpd.id = b.batchPricingDetailsId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the date comparison in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(bt.transactionQuantity * bpd.unitPrice), 0)
FROM batchTransaction bt
JOIN (
    SELECT bt.productId, max(bt.dateCreated) AS maxDate
    FROM batchTransaction bt
    WHERE bt.organisationId = '714361434540086498' AND bt.dateCreated < 1689877800000
    GROUP BY bt.productId
) AS filtered_data ON bt.productId = filtered_data.productId AND bt.dateCreated = filtered_data.maxDate
LEFT JOIN batch b ON b.id = bt.batchId
LEFT JOIN batchPricingDetails bpd ON bpd.id = b.batchPricingDetailsId;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Depending on how old your MySQL is, this construct may be *very* poorly optimized; avoid it:

  ```
  WHERE (a,b) IN ...
  ```
- Also, try to change this to a `JOIN` or `EXISTS` (as you did in second query):

  ```
  ... IN ( SELECT ... )
  ```
- Index:

  ```
  batchTransaction:  INDEX(organisationId, productId, dateCreated)
  ```
- "giving erroneous results by a margin of greater than 10X" -- Eh?  More specifics, please.